# HBase with YARN throws ERROR

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop-yarn

I'm using Hadoop 2.5.1 with HBase 0.98.11 on Ubuntu 14.04

I could run it in Pseudo-distributed mode. Now that I want to run on distributed mode. I follow the instruction from sites and end up having an error in RUNTIME called "Error: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration" (while there is no error when I compile the code).

After trying things, I found that if I comment the mapreduce.framework.name in mapred-site.xml and also stuffs in yarn-site, I could be able to run the hadoop successfully.

But I think it's the single-node running (I have no idea, just guessing by comparing the running time to what I ran in Pseudo and there is no MR in slave's node jps when running the job on master).

Here are some of my conf:

hdfs-site

```
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>2</value>
<description>Default block replication.
The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
</description>
</property>
<!-- <property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>-->
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.permissions</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
```

mapred-site

```
 <property>
   <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
   <value>localhost:54311</value>
   <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
   at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
   and reduce task.
   </description>
 </property>

 <!--<property>
   <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
   <value>yarn</value>
 </property>-->
```

yarn-site

```
 <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->

 <!--<property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
     <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
     <value>10.1.1.177:8032</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
     <value>10.1.1.177:8030</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
     <value>10.1.1.177:8031</value>
 </property>-->
```

Thank you so much for every help

UPDATE: I try making some changes to the yarn-site by adding yarn.applicaton.classpath like this

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/yarn.png?_subject_uid=51053996&w=AABeDJfRp_D31RiVHqBWn0r9naQR_lFVJXIlwvCwjdhCAQ

The error changed to EXIT CODE.

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/exitcode.jpg?_subject_uid=51053996&w=AAAQ-bYoRSrQV3yFq36vEDPnAB9aIHnyOQfnvt2cUHn5IQ

UPDATE2: In syslog of the application logs it says

> 2015-04-24 20:34:59,164 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Created MRAppMaster for application appattempt_1429792550440_0035_000002
>   2015-04-24 20:34:59,589 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
>   2015-04-24 20:34:59,610 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
>   2015-04-24 20:34:59,616 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpConfig.setPolicy(Lorg/apache/hadoop/http/HttpConfig$Policy;)V
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1364)
>   2015-04-24 20:34:59,621 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: MRAppMaster received a signal. Signaling RMCommunicator and JobHistoryEventHandler.

Any suggestions pls

Comment: please add error trace

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what's error trace. Btw, the error shown when running is just the "Error: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration" after Map 0% Reduce 0%.
Thanks.

Comment: This is what it came out when I run the jobs (dont know if this is error trace you mentioned) https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/Pics/error.jpg?_subject_uid=51053996&w=AADKyjbvWHtBa_RkYsWt2AhhBNV2siP7EIM81q-4irjR1w
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sticking with the problem for more than 3 days (maybe it's from my misunderstanding the concept), I can fix the problem by adding HADOOP_CLASSPATH (like what I did when setting up the pseudo-distribute in hadoop-env) into the yarn-env.

I have no idea much in detail. But, yeah, hope this may be able to help someone in the future.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you didn't set up your hadoop cluster correctly please follow these steps :

*Hadoop Configuration:*

step 1 : edit `hadoop-env.sh` as following:

```
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

step 2 : Now create a directory and set the required ownerships and permissions

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp
$ sudo chown hduser:hadoop /app/hadoop/tmp
# ...and if you want to tighten up security, chmod from 755 to 750...
$ sudo chmod 750 /app/hadoop/tmp
```

step 3 : edit `core-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
</property>
```

step 5 : edit `mapred-site.xml`

```
  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
```

step 6 : edit `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
          <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:///home/hduser/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:///home/hduser/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

step 7 : edit `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
   <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
```

finally format your hdfs (You need to do this the first time you set up a Hadoop cluster)

```
$ /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

*Hbase Configuration:*

edit you `hbase-site.xml`:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
</property> 

<property>
   <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>  
   <value>localhost</value>
</property>

<property>   
  <name>dfs.replication</name>   
  <value>1</value>    
</property>

 <property>       
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>  
  <value>2181</value>                                                                                 
 </property>

 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hbase/zookeeper</value>   
 </property>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I think that's all like what I did. After I finished setting up Hadoop cluster, I tried running PI and WordCount job, and it worked successfully. So I have no idea what I really did wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mean that's what I did before facing the problem. Then I tried running jobs with HBase and the ERROR shown up. I tried commented the mapreduce.framework.name and I can run the jobs properly again BUT it seems that it only ran on 1 node.
Thanks

Comment: In case you still confuse the idea due to my bad communication skill. I set up mapred-site and yarn-site kind of like the one you post (but in yarn-site I have yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class, yarn.resourcemanager.address, yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address, yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address)
and I can run "hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.1.jar pi 5 50" SUCCESSFULLY. But when it comes to the program with HBase, error's thrown.

Comment: try to copy the hadoop-core-*.jar from your HADOOP_HOME and commons-collections-x.y.z.jar from HADOOP_HOME/lib folder into your HBASE_HOME/lib folder.

Comment: I dont have both of them in the according folders. I'm using Hadoop 2.5.1

Comment: When I usually compiling javac, I would include "hadoop-common-2.5.1.jar" and "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.1.jar", so I try copy both files to the HBASE_HOME/lib and running the program. Unfortunately, the problem still persists.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind is it. Here is the picture of the running result. https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/Pics/error.jpg?_subject_uid=51053996&w=AADKyjbvWHtBa_RkYsWt2AhhBNV2siP7EIM81q-4irjR1w
Thanks

Comment: I couldn't open the link

Comment: May I ask you more things. HADOOP_CLASSPATH in hadoop-env, mapreduce.application.classpath in mapred-site, yarn.application.classpath in yarn-site -- which one(s) I need to set up the environment for hadoop+hbase multi-node cluster? (really confused with these ones)

Comment: Haddop classpath in hadoop env

Comment: update: I can run the jobs without any ERROR. Btw, it stucks at map 4% until the timeout's shown.
http://imgur.com/lZs1mcT
Any ways to fix this? Thanks sir.

Comment: I add the same thing as I did in hadoop-env into yarn-env and it works. Could you please explain to me in detail what i was doing wrong.. (and why there's no sites telling me to do that).
Really thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope. I added classpath into yarn-env and things seem to work. After a day, the error comes back again :(

What I did for now is stop using HBase and try implementing something quite the same as I want using ReadFile and MultiOutput.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Spark on Yarn and was getting the same error. Actually, the spark jar had a internal dependency of hadoop-client and hadoop-mapreduce-client-* jars pointing to older 2.2.0 versions. So, I included these entries in my POM with the Hadoop version that I was running and did a clean build.

This resolved the issue for me. Hope this helps someone.